# converting set to a map groovy

Tags: grails, groovy

I have my logic in my postprocess to process the values of devices and files as below :(changed this to set from map as it was overriding the values)

```
def deviceFiles = devices.inject([] as Set) { deviceFiles, device ->
            def v = device.key.split( /\./ )[0]
            deviceFiles << [ (device.value), files[ v ] ]
        }
```

output : deviceFiles :[[Acer C6, Tetris.apk], [Motorola Droid Milestone, Tetris.apk], [Acer C6, TheSims3.apk], [HTC Desire, TheSims3.apk]] --- looks good to be displayed

These values are to be passed as a map/properties so that the data would be displayed properly without any cast exceptions, which I am finding tough..

when it is looped through the set

```
deviceFiles.each { device  ->
            mapping.put("${device}", "${file}")
        }
```

output : mapping :[HTC Desire:TheSims3.apk, Motorola Droid Milestone:Tetris.apk, Acer C6:Tetris.apk] -- which is not correct (Acer C6:TheSims3.apk has been overriden)

Am I missing something here in sending the expected values into map? or it is not possible to send the values of set through map(as map always eliminates the duplicates when i am iterating through devices) ???

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use [collectEntries](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/groovy-jdk/java/lang/Iterable.html#collectEntries()):

```
def deviceFiles = devices.collectEntries {
    device -> [device.value, device.key.split(/\./)[0]]
}
```

Comment: my groovy version is not supporting collectEntries, so I have implemented inject

Comment: @JarredOlson, the collect{} worked but my requirement is not fulfilled here, as its saying cannot cast object arraylist to properties...hmmmm...

Comment: If the inject works I'd go with that. Otherwise you could loop and create the Properties the old fashioned way :)

Comment: actually the inject worked as a map and as a set separately...but may be to convert the set into map, i need to loop and create properties...hmmmm...thanks for the response ...everyone...

Comment: Hi, I tried to loop through the set, but when it is added to map again it overrides the duplicate values, if its added to set then its incompatible with the properties...hmmmm I am editing the question...

Answer (score 2):

You can use `groupBy` for this. Assuming your set consists of:

```
def deviceFiles = [["Acer", "test.apk"], ["Acer", "abc.apk"], ["HTC", "qwer.apk"]]

def mapping = deviceFiles.groupBy { it[0] }
```

Will result in:

```
["Acer": [["Acer", "test.apk"], ["Acer", "abc.apk"]], "HTC": [["HTC", "qwer.apk"]]]
```

Comment: thanks for the response, but my intended output is not as above...I will give this a try if needed. thanks again